# Having trouble with a many to many linq select

Tags: .net, linq

I have three tables created as so:

[image]

What I'd like to do is select an Attendee where an AdministratorAttendee record exists for a given AttendeeId and AdministratorId.

What I've tried is this:

```
var result = (from a in dc.Attendees
              from aa in dc.AdministratorAttendees
              where aa.AdministratorId == this.CurrentAdminId && a.AttendeeId == _attendee.AttendeeId
              select a);
```

But it's returning no results despite the fact an Attendee, Administrator and AdministratorAttendee record exists for the given Ids.

What is the correct linq query to use?

Thanks

Comment: What does `this` refer to?  What is the current object?

Comment: the current page class. Basically CurrentAdminId and _attendee.AttendeeId are two parameters

Comment: What's the type of the id fields?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this way?

```
var result = (from a in dc.Attendees
                  join aa in dc.AdministratorAttendees
                  on new { aa.AdministratorId, a.AttendeeId } equals 
                     new { this.CurrentAdminId, _attendee.AttendeeId } 
                  select a);
```

Comment: You can't use `equals` twice